# android service web connection

Tags: android, service, inputstream

In my app I've got a class that i use to get data from my server. It works fine in every `Activity` that i made, but this time i want to use it in `Service` subclass, which is (services) new to me in 100%.

I found an issue in this line:

```
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

This is a place when my web class fires Exception:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Is there any major difference between using it in activities and services?

Comment: Could you please post what is the excption and the logcat

Comment: post edited, it's android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` means you are running a network oriented  task on the main thread "UI Thread". Android now forbids this as it renders the UI unresponsive during the network call.

To solve this you need to make the network call in another thread. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is perfectly suited to this.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i figured it out, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception?answertab=active#tab-top) was the problem. I used AsyncTask in my `Service` and it runs well now.